# Does HTML Document style affect SEO?

Tags: seo, javascript, react-js, next.js

Does a non-styled HTML Document affect SEO negatively? Which of these examples is better for SEO?

#### Example 1

[image]

#### Example 2

[image]

Here is a lighthouse result for both examples

#### Example 1

[image]

#### Example 2

[image]

As you can see, the first example loads faster, but I'm not sure if that will negatively affect SEO.
Are styled documents easy for search engines to read the content?

Comment: You'll get some ignorant answers that have nothing to do with SEO. So carefully read Google's Search Engine Optimization Starter Guide so you'll be able to tune those out: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?ref_topic=9268559

Comment: @Steve thanks for sharing the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styled HTML is better for SEO because usability is a search engine ranking factor. Unstyled documents are ugly and hard to use.  When users land on such pages from search, they will be unhappy.  Many of them will us the back button and find other sites to use.  Google will notice this behavior and worsen rankings for pages that users don't like.

On the other hand, performance is also a search engine ranking factor.  Improving site performance can help rankings.  However, for performance improvements to help SEO, they usually have to be on the order of seconds.  Spending a couple hundred milliseconds to apply styles to pages isn't going to make a huge difference to SEO in terms of performance but *will* make a huge difference in terms of usabilty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful information :)

Answer (score 1):

Certainly there is no difference in the same working conditions
But if the elements and their arrangement are such that it slows down or increases the rendering time, the issue is different.
In addition, the URL of a different source may slow down or increase the page loading speed
In this case, yes, the difference in templates has a big impact on the SEO